# How to create CSV from a text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to create a CSV file from a textfile with billing data about my calls. My textfile has a structure like:

```
01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 New York 3:35 0,00 0,00
```

I create the CSV using:

```
require 'csv'
  @calls = File.new("modified_billing", "r")
  CSV.open("new.csv", 'wb', write_headers: true,
    headers: ["Date", "Time", "Phone number","City","Duration", "Cost", "Cost of call"]) do |csv|
    @calls.each do |call|
      csv << call.split(" ")
    end
  end
```

It works for cities which have singular name, but obviously it doesn't for "New York", "Las Vegas", etc. because it creates two columns out of them.

Comment: you have to identify if the textfile you will be getting will be in the same format everytime. Looking at the pattern of your textfile, i guess you can use regex to chop off the numbers part up to `New York` and then chop that off to process the remaining data

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but how should I in the same time separate numbers from each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've almost got it. Here's a simple way of doing it without regex:

```
string = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 New York 3:35 0,00 0,00'
data = string.split(' ')

data.shift(3)
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775"]

data.pop(3)
# => ["3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]

data.join(' ')
# => "New York"

# putting it together
first, third, second = data.shift(3), data.pop(3), [data.join(' ')]
csv << first + second + third
```

Something more compact, though a little harder to read:

```
data = call.split(' ')
csv << [data.shift(3), data.pop(3)].insert(1, data.join(' ')).flatten
```

---

Comment: Very nice!  You should add the final step for the OP, pulling it together... `first = data.shift(3); third = data.pop(3); second = [data.join(' ')]; csv << first + second + third`

Comment: Will do! Thanks :)

Comment: ha, even better :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch'a ways to solve this. Here's how I've done similar things in the past:

```
str = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 New York 3:35 0,00 0,00'
/(\S+) (\S+) (\d+) (.+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775", "New York", "3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]

str = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 Chicago 3:35 0,00 0,00'
/(\S+) (\S+) (\d+) (.+) (\S+) (\S+) (\S+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775", "Chicago", "3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]
```

Since you know the fields are usually space delimited you can use those to your advantage.

If you need to validate the fields a bit more:

```
str = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 New York 3:35 0,00 0,00'
/([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) (\d+) (\D+?) ([\d+:]+) ([\d,]+) ([\d,]+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775", "New York", "3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]

str = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 Chicago 3:35 0,00 0,00'
/([\d.]+) ([\d:]+) (\d+) (\D+?) ([\d+:]+) ([\d,]+) ([\d,]+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775", "Chicago", "3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]
```

Sometimes I've used something more like a template:

```
str = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 New York 3:35 0,00 0,00'
/((?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{4}) ((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}) (\d+) (\D+?) (\d+:\d+) ([\d,]+) ([\d,]+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775", "New York", "3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]

str = '01.02.2016 10:35:49 8998775 Chicago 3:35 0,00 0,00'
/((?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{4}) ((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}) (\d+) (\D+?) (\d+:\d+) ([\d,]+) ([\d,]+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["01.02.2016", "10:35:49", "8998775", "Chicago", "3:35", "0,00", "0,00"]
```

Where:

- `\d{2}` means "two digits".
- `(?:\d{2}\.)` means "consider two digits and a `.` as a group but don't capture ("remember") it.
- `(?:\d{2}\.){2}` means "do it twice".
- `((?:\d{2}\.){2}\d{4})` means "remember all that plus the next four digits".

Knowing that you can work out the rest of the pattern.

The advantage is once the patterns are figured out it's a matter of figuring out how many times they repeat. If the source text changes later then it's pretty simple to tweak the numbers. And this is the power of regular expressions, they're great when you have patterns that repeat.

All that said, I prefer to not use regular expressions because they tend to be fragile and, if you're not aware of how the engine parses, they can *really* slow down your code. Instead I'd go with something like [Damien's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40340974/128421), using `split` to take apart the string, then `shift` and `pop` resulting in the city being left.

Comment: Nice explanation! I love it when I girlfriend says "(?:\d{2}\.){2}"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Regexp that matches your example. Without other lines, it's hard to tell if it will work for every call. You'll get a "Cannot parse" warning for calls that don't get matched by the Regexp.
If there are multiples spaces or tabs, you can replace all the ' ' by '\s+'.

```
if call=~/(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d) (\d+) (.*?) (\d+:\d\d) (\d+,\d\d) (\d+,\d\d)/ then
  csv << Regexp.last_match.captures
else
  puts "Cannot parse : #{call}"
end
```

Comment: Your regex can be greatly simplified. Look at using `{n}` and/or repeating non-capturing groups.

Comment: Sure, I could use \d{2} instead of \d\d, but I don't find it more readable, and it's actually longer. It's only worth it for \d{4}. Also, I want every group to be capturing to get an Array directly. How would your example look like? If you want to nitpick, "and/or" is just "or" http://www.ewriteonline.com/using-andor-in-a-sentence-is-just-plain-dumb/ ;)